# Extract frames from multiple tiff format images

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have a dataset of tiff images that needs to be decomposed. Each file has 50 frames and currently i'm decomposing one by one, but compared to the amount of images that i have, it'll take a long long time to decompose every single one of them. My goal is for every tiff file inside  a folder, i'd like to decompose and store them inside a separate folder, where every tiff image will always have 50 frames, for example:

> inside C:\Dataset\tiff-images\

i have tiff-image1, tiff-image2, tiffimage3, tiffimage4.

Still inside the same directory i have the folders: tiff-image1, tiff-image2, tiff-image3, tiff-image4.

Basically, what i would like is to simply iterate through as many tiff-images inside the directory and decompose them inside their respective folder by creating a folder in-case there isn't.

The way i am trying right now, isnt exactly optimal and will take me a long time to do this process:

```
imagepath = "tiff-image1.tif"
path = "C:/Dataset/tiff-images/" + imagepath
img = Image.open(path)

for i in range(50):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('C:/Dataset/tiff-images/tiff-image1-folder1/tiff-image1-decomp.tif%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break

imagepath = "tiff-image2.tif"
path = "C:/Dataset/tiff-images/" + imagepath
img = Image.open(path)

for i in range(50):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('C:/Dataset/tiff-images/tiff-image2-folder2/tiff-image2-decomp.tif%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break

imagepath = "tiff-image3.tif"
path = "C:/Dataset/tiff-images/" + imagepath
img = Image.open(path)

for i in range(50):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('C:/Dataset/tiff-images/tiff-image3-folder3/tiff-image3-decomp.tif%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break

imagepath = "tiff-image4.tif"
path = "C:/Dataset/tiff-images/" + imagepath
img = Image.open(path)

for i in range(50):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('C:/Dataset/tiff-images/tiff-image4-folder4/tiff-image4-decomp.tif%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os` module for such kind of automation.
Check this:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

# enter the main folder path here
path = './'

lsdir = os.listdir(path)

for f in lsdir:
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        file, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if ext in ['.tif', '.tiff']:
            fldr = os.path.join(path, file)
            if not os.path.isdir(fldr):
                os.mkdir(fldr)

            imgpath = os.path.join(path, f)
            img = Image.open(imgpath)
            for i in range(50):
                try:
                    img.seek(i)
                    img.save(f'{fldr}/decomp{i}.tif')
                except EOFError:
                    break
```

Comment: os or glob if you need to filter out only images and for recurrent search.